# For which $a$ is the solution of $x''+2ax'+x=f(t)$ bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the differential equation $x''+2ax'+x=f(t)$.
If $f(t)=0$, for which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ does the differential equation have non-trivial solutions that are bounded on $\mathbb{R}$?

What if $f(t)=\cos t$?

Edit: Solutions for $f(t)=0$ are $\exp((-a-\sqrt{a^2-1})t)$ and $\exp((-a+\sqrt{a^2-1})t)$

Comment: With $f(t)=0$ it is not hard to write down an explicit solution in terms of (possibly complex) exponentials. With $f(t)=\cos(t)$ there still is not *that* much work to be done (you just need to find a particular solution).

Comment: @Ian a particular solution is sin(t)/2, but how do the solutions in terms of exponentials help me?

Comment: @BobStork - welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a nice exercise question. Please tell us what you have done so far: Partial answers, solution ideas, perhaps a similar problem that you know how to solve.

Comment: A particular solution in general is not $\sin(t)/2$; the situation depends rather strongly on the value of $a$. Also, your exponential solutions are missing an important factor of $t$. So the homogeneous solutions are $\exp((-a+\sqrt{a^2-1})t)$ and $\exp((-a-\sqrt{a^2-1})t)$. What matters is the real part of these two numbers $-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}$ and $-a-\sqrt{a^2-1}$. When both of these have positive real part, all solutions to the homogeneous equation except for the trivial solution $x \equiv 0$ are unbounded. What happens if just one of them has positive real part?

Comment: @Ian I forgot the $t$ (sorry), and a particular solution is sin(t)/2a?

Comment: Still wrong; you need to use the exponential solutions that you already worked out.

Comment: @Ian what happens if only one of them has positive real part?

Comment: The answer (for the inhomogeneous case) is easily obtained for the Fourier transform of $x(t)$ and from that $x(t)$ itself.

Comment: @urgje I'd rather not use Fourier transforms

Comment: @ian I dont see why sin(t)/(2a) doesnt work?

Comment: Wait, you mean with $f(t)=\cos(t)$? In that case you are right (except when $a=0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider  $x''+2ax'+x=0$. The characteristic equation is $r^{2}+2ar+1=0$. The roots are: $r=-a\pm\sqrt{a^{2}-1}$. If $|a|>1$ then the roots are real and different and the solution are
$$
y=c_{1}e^{(-a+\sqrt{a^2-1})t}+c_{2}e^{(-a-\sqrt{a^2-1})t},
$$
If $|a|=1$ then 
$$
y=(c_{1}+c_{2}t)e^{-at}
$$
and if $|a|<1$ then 
$$
y=e^{-at}\Big(c_{1}\cos(t\sqrt{1-a^{2}})+c_{2}\sin(t\sqrt{1-a^{2}})\Big)
$$
You see that in the third case if $0\leq a<1$ then the equation has bounded solutions in $\mathbb{R}$. In the first case you can also verify the desired values for $a$. If $f(t)=\cos(t)$ is a particular solution, $y_{p}$ will be added to your solution, i.e $y=c_{1}y_{1}+c_{2}y_{2}+y_{p}$. In this situation $y_{p}$ will be changed if $|a|>1, |a|<1$ or $|a|=1$. So, you have to check in each case separately. Specifically, if $a\neq 0$ then the particular solution is
$$
y_{p}=A\cos(t)+B\sin(t)
$$
where $A$ and $B$ depend on $a$. So in this case $y_{p}$ is bounded on the real line. If $a=0$, then 
$$
y_{p}=(A+Bt)\cos(t)+(C+Dt)\sin(t)
$$
where  $A, B, C$ and $D$ depend on $a$. In this case $y_{p}$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you also explain what happens to $y_p$?

Comment: isnt that a particular solution for all a except 0?

Comment: For example in the case $|a|>1$, the particular solution is $y_{p}=\frac{1}{2a}\sin(t)$ which is bounded in $R$.

Comment: please see my previous comment

Comment: follow my continued discussion in my answer

Comment: @BobStork, see my answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking to be sure that $y_p$ is not bounded, you need to check that $B$ and $D$ are not both zero.

Comment: Surly! it is important to check that $B$ and $D$ are not zero.